# Filter previous data in grouped dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

Given the `data.frame` below, how can I obtain a genre history (by player) for each game deemed interesting?

```
player <- c(rep (1,3), rep(2,4))
game <- c(seq(1:3), seq(1:4))
genre <- c("JnR", "Ego", "RPG", "RPG", "Sports", "JnR", "Sim")
interesting <- c("no", rep(c("no","yes"),3))
                 
playerhist <- data.frame (player, game, genre, interesting)

> playerhist

  player game  genre interesting
1      1    1    JnR          no
2      1    2    Ego          no
3      1    3    RPG         yes
4      2    1    RPG          no
5      2    2 Sports         yes
6      2    3    JnR          no
7      2    4    Sim         yes
```

Desired output:

```
  player game genre_history
1      1    1           JnR
2      1    2           Ego
3      2    1           RPG
4      2    1           RPG
5      2    2        Sports
6      2    3           JnR
```

So for each interesting game I'd like to include all the previous rows for the corresponding player. Including information from the 'interesting' column is not required as shown in the desired output, but if solutions include it anyway, that would also be fine. This column would read `c('no','no','no','no','yes','no')`.

A solution using `dplyr` would be preferred.

Comment: `playerhist |> filter(interesting == "yes")`. Note that your example output includes rows marked as "no" so the result from this code won't march your example output.

Comment: Almost all the rows in your output are for games where `interesting == "no"`, except player 2, game 2, genre_history "Sports".

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `playerhist |> filter(any(interesting == "yes"), .by = player)` to keep all row for players that any interesting games?

Comment: @LMc @Gregor That's exactly the challenge I'm facing. The real dataset is considerably bigger and there are much more cases like player2, game 2. One approach would be to sort of get a df for each interesting game and player including all previous game entries (result could be a list of dfs), then delete the last row in each of these dfs (interesting = yes) via ```lapply``` and ```slice``` and ultimately use ```bind_rows```.

Comment: It's unclear the combination that would result in a successful selection. Player 1, played interesting game 3, but this line is not in the desired output.

Comment: @guasi It's not in the desired output bc for player 1 we only need the two previous rows. But with player 2 having played two interesting games, we need the previous row and for the second game of interest it would be the three previous rows, this time including game 2. I would assume that from-to row selections for each interesting game would do the job but I'm struggling with the nested structure for players having multiple interesting games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Here it is for those trying to solve a similar problem:

```
library(dplyr)

#-------------------------------
# #1 number of interesting games for each player
# #2 splitting df into list of dfs for each player
# #3 copy & append df for -> max(.$int_game) times 
# #4 numbering of dfs using a new number every time game == 1
# #5 splitting df into list of dfs for each player & df_num
# #6 count occurrences of interesting == 'yes'
# #7 set cutpoint to slice determined by cut1 == df_num for the first time
# #8 slice from row 1:row at which cut2 == 1 and omit the last row
#-------------------------------

gamehist <- playerhist %>%
  group_by (player) %>%
  mutate (int_game = cumsum(str_detect(interesting, "yes"))) %>% #1
  ungroup () %>%
  base::split (., .$player, drop = FALSE) %>% #2 
  lapply (., function (df) { 
    df %>% 
      .[rep(1:nrow(.), max(.$int_game)),] %>% #3 
      mutate (df_num = cumsum(.$game == 1)) %>% #4 
      return ()
    }) %>% 
  bind_rows () %>%
  base::split (., list(.$player, .$df_num), drop = TRUE) %>% #5
  lapply (., function (df2) {
    df2 %>% 
      mutate (cut1 = cumsum (str_detect(interesting, "yes")), #6
              cut2 = if_else (cut1 == df_num, 1, 0)) %>% #7
      slice (1:which(cut2 == 1)-1) %>% #8
      return ()
    }) %>% 
  bind_rows () %>%
  select (player, game, genre)

gamehist

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  player  game genre 
   <dbl> <int> <chr> 
1      1     1 JnR   
2      1     2 Ego   
3      2     1 RPG   
4      2     1 RPG   
5      2     2 Sports
6      2     3 JnR
```